# Platform Builder command line building

Tags: c, visual-studio, windows-ce, platform-builder

I'm building a project from the command line using WinCE platform builder, and I need RTTI to be enabled, so that my project works correctly. I tried setting the option `RTTI="YES`" in the sources and in the makefile of each dir, and I also tried to add it at the end of  `CDEFINES`, but when I try to build the project, I get the `D9025` warnings, which says that my `"/GR was overriden by /GR-" ( enable RTTI was overriden by don't enable RTTI )`.
My question is, how can I find out where that option is set, so that I can modify it?

---

The thing is that we only copy the sources to some dirs, we specify them in a file named "sources", and then we proceed with the build by issuing the following command: `build`

What I would like to know is, where is build taking it's options from? What is the name of the file?

Answer (score 1):

**Command-Line Warning D9025**

If two options specify contradictory or incompatible directives, the directive specified or implied in the option farthest to the right on the command line is used.

If you get this warning when compiling from the development environment, and are not sure where the conflicting options are coming from, consider the following:

An option can be specified either in code or in the project's project settings. If you look at the compiler's Command Line Property Pages and if you see the conflicting options in the All Options field then the options are set in the project's property pages, otherwise, the options are set in source code.

If the options are set in project's property pages, look on the compiler's Preprocessor property page (with the project node selected in the Solution Explorer). If you do not see the option set there, check the Preprocessor property page settings for each source code file (in Solution Explorer) to make sure it's not added there.

If the options are set in code it could be set either in code or in the windows headers. You might try creating a preprocessed file (/P) and search it for the symbol.

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k3f51f1(vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking in sources.cmn, which is a common sources file for the entire build system.  If it's not there, keep in mind that every SOURCES file can alter compiler variables for it's folder, plus the makefiles can also alter things.  To add to the fun, the system and platform build batch files can also play with environment variables, that in turn may adjust settings.